# D3.JS treemap inconsistent zoom behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to do a menu of sorts with a d3.js treemap. It mostly works, but I'm having a few glitches that I can't pinpoint.

Basically, *sometimes* my chart doesn't zoom correctly and instead of seeing the children take the whole SVG area, they show up "unzoomed".

I suspect it must have something to do with the animation's timing vs. some data manipulation for hiding/showing the different nodes, but can't actually figure it out. Other thing I thought might be borking up the behavior relates to the click events being registered by both "parent" and "children" nodes.

I have a similar example setup in [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/gageja/edit?js,output).

So, I was wondering how I could register/unregister click events in the parent/child nodes on zoom - if that's even the problem - and also if there was a simpler or less-error prone way to change the nodes' visibility.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I didn't understand very well the problem. I clicked in the food icon, then "street food" and then the zoom was restored to the root. Is this behaviour that you are talking about?

Comment: @jprivillaso no... The bad behaviour I'm talking about occurs *sometimes* if you click a rectangle (but not the icon).

Comment: I guess I reproduced the error. Is it when you click fast in the boxes, then all the nodes appear kind on the same level ?

Comment: Yes, they appear at the same level, but it does not relate to how fast you click, I think. It has to do with click events being registered by both child and parent nodes, I believe.

Comment: In the `clickedG` function, if you `console.log(d.name)`, you'll see that even when you click a parent icon, the `d` beneath it is the one calling the `.on("click", clickedG)`... This is why I believe that registering/unregistering the click events is the way to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this might be a bit unorthodox, but I found a way to overcome this.

Basically, instead of trying to mess around with event registering/unregistering, I simply ran the zoom only if the click wasn't from the node at the current zoom level.

So, in my `zoom` function, I wrapped the zoom handling in an `if` check:

```
function zoom(d) {

  if(node!=d){

    // the rest remains the same

  }
}
```

Either way, I still think that this was happening due to the source elements where the click events were coming from being overlapped in the SVG area - simply put, the click event was being triggered by several overlapping elements, being the first (topmost) in the SVG tree order triggered inadvertently.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/fehefa/1/edit?js)'s a working version.

Hope this helps someone else!

**EDIT:** This solution isn't perfect, though. Now sometimes the click just doesn't do anything - But it's better than borking the UI. If anyone has other ideas, they're welcome.